# Swift 3.3 deprecation cause for false==true 500 failure?

Tags: ios, swift

I released a new version of an app without upgrading from Swift 3.3 to 4. An app user with an iPhone X reported seeing this error:

[image]

`false == true 500`

I can't replicate this error in the iPhone X simulator. Would Swift 3.3 cause an error like this, even though the app is running fine on the simulator?

Comment: I know it's a poorly constructed question. I'm not a Swift developer, but was tasked to fix it. Any help is appreciated, I can't find a definitive answer online.

Comment: 500 looks like a HTTP status code, there might be a problem with your servers?

Comment: yep I found the issue in server logs, thank you @Sweeper

Answer (score 0):

The issue was server side – 500 referred to a 500 HTTP error, while `false==true` was the server side error message.